# Using exec and tee to redirect logs to stdout and a log file in the same time

Tags: bash, logs, tee, exec

In a bash script, how can I redirect all standard outputs to a log file and `tee` the output on the screen using `exec` ?

```
log_file="$HOME/logs/install.txt-`date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'`"
[ -f "$log_file" ] || touch "$log_file"
exec 1>> $log_file 2>&1
```

This code redirect all the log to the log file but not to the screen .

Comment: May be the answer looks the same, but it was not the same question.

Comment: No, it is the exact same question. The first sentence describes what it's trying to do, and it's exactly what you're trying to do: "redirect all output to one file, debug log as well as to the terminal"

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) with [`&` redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error) and [`exec`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-exec):

```
exec &> >(tee -a "$log_file")
echo "This will be logged to the file and to the screen"
```

`$log_file` will contain the output of the script and any subprocesses, and the output will also be printed to the screen.

- `>(...)` starts the process `...` and returns a file representing its standard input.
- `exec &> ...` redirects both standard output and standard error into `...` for the remainder of the script (use just `exec > ...` for stdout only).
- `tee -a` appends its standard input to the file, and also prints it to the screen.

Comment: It works, but sometimes I still get output when I already have my console prompt, resulting in a mixed output.

Comment: @Halfgaar - That is expected as exec replace the process including file descriptors for STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR - effectively detaching it from the terminal but tee continues to emit anything it receives.

Comment: On Mac this just simply hangs forever!

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne that may be something to [ask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) another question about, but [in general, no, it doesn't](https://pastebin.com/RVuFG7Vp).

Comment: I thought I had the same result on Linux as Praveen, but it turned out that I was at the command prompt. If I type something, I get _command not found_. If I add an `exit` to the script, I get my command prompt back. I'm testing using a script with just a single `echo` statement.

Comment: Is `$` a special command character or are you writing to a file names $log_file in the current directory?

Comment: Looks like this method fails on Alpine Linux which uses busybox `sh` instead of `bash`: `sh: syntax error: unexpected redirection`

Comment: @xref This question is specifically about Bash, but the accepted answer in the duplicate question ought to work under POSIX sh at the cost of wrapping the body in braces, with more or less the same execution.

Answer (score 8):

```
exec >> $log_file 2>&1 && tail $log_file
```

Comment: maybe `tail -f`?