# How to log from inside the script along with stdout

Tags: shell-script, scripting, stdout, tee

I am aware that I can log using `tee`

But I want to log from inside my script, at the same time display the content on the `stdout`.

Example, my code looks something like this:

```
    names=$(print("name1 name2 name3 name4"))

    for name in names
    do
       echo "Current Name: " $name 
       related_job= ps -ef | grep $name | awk '{print $9}' >> File.dat
       echo "related job: " $related_job
    done
```

Now, this block will certainly `echo` at stdout, but I even want to log this to a log file, say `script_name.log`.

Also, I am calling the script through a scheduler and sue to come constraint I can't use `script_name | tee log_file` . I can just call the script by the script name.

What could be the solution to this?

Comment: see here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145651/using-exec-and-tee-to-redirect-logs-to-stdout-and-a-log-file-in-the-same-time

Comment: As far as I know, `tee` has no problem working within a script.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash`, you can also combine bash's `exec >&`, to redirect all output from the script, with process substitution.

e.g. something like the following at the start of your script:

```
LOGFILE='/tmp/teelog.log'
savelog "$LOGFILE"
exec &> >(tee "$LOGFILE")
```

This will redirect both stdout & stderr to stdout and to $LOGFILE, using `savelog` to rotate and keep older logs (7 by default) every time the script is run.

Comment: ,This isn't working for me. As soon as i add the above line at the start of my script, the script gets stuck :(   `exec &> >(tee "$LOGFILE")` is behaving very strangely, it is creating a ?? ( zero byte) file in the directory rather than the log file name i specify

Comment: Is your script a bash script, and have you defined $LOGFILE?

Comment: its ksh script , but i even tried with bash. And yes i did mention the file name in place of $LOGFILE

Answer (score 0):

Very simple; use `tee` with its option flags *inside* the script, not when you are calling the script.

At the end of any `echo` line, append `| tee -a logfile`

In place of any `> file` redirect, you can use `| tee file` to also send the text to stdout.  (This overwrites the file instead of appending, just like the `> file` redirect.)

In place of any `>> mylog.log` redirect, you can use `| tee -a mylog.log`.

If you have many many lines involving output, I recommend making a simple function in your script to replace echo, which will look something like `echo $* | tee -a logfile`.  (Not sure of the `$*` part; I haven't done a lot with functions within scripts.)

Answer (score 0):

`tee` might be what you want. Add this lines in the beginning of the script:

```
exec 1> >(tee -a logfile)
exec 2>&1
```

The first line redirects and appends (`-a`) everything from the standard ouput stream to the `logfile` and prints it to the screen. The second line redirects the standard error to standard output.

---

It is also possible with `awk`. Specially if you want the output to the screen, but logged with a date:

```
exec 1> >(awk -W interactive '{"date" | getline d; print $0; print d, $0 >> "logfile"}')
exec 2>&1
```

`awk` must be set to interactive, that awk writes unbuffered to standard output. If you want you can redirect the standard error to something different by (maybe another log file):

```
exec 2> >(...)
```