# How to extract every command line, exit code and stdout/stderr in one script

Tags: bash, shell-script

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

I am trying to write a script that for every command the user is executing in Bash will save the following to a file:

1. The full command that the user typed
2. The exit code of the command (AFAIK `script` doesn't provide this)
3. Content of the stdout and stderr that the command produced.

I was able to implement both 1 and 2 very quickly using the https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec

I am stuck with 3.

I want to create a script that I can put in `~/.bash_profile` for easy setup.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save all the terminal output to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200637/save-all-the-terminal-output-to-a-file)

Comment: `script` does not save the exit code of the command IIRC.

Comment: Yeah, thats correct but didn't you need help for third point only now?

Comment: I need help in understanding how to combine the 3 requirements in 1 script.

Comment: simplest method: type `echo $?` or similar after each command in `script`.

Comment: Another downside of `script` is that if the user types `TAB` to autocomplete it puts special characters in the output file which I will have to clean up later.

Comment: `script` doesn't save the exit code, but you could add that exit code to your prompt (possibly only when non-zero, which is a very sensible thing to do in any case), so it would then be saved as part of the output.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145654/4323) you can use `exec` and `&>` redirection with `tee` to capture standard output and standard error to a file.

One thing I'm wondering about is whether you want to have a different capture per command (as can be understood from your requirement for "every command" and the assertion that `script` cannot be used) or whether you just want to capture an entire session in a log file.

If its the latter, then running `script` at the beginning of the session and then implementing whatever else you did inside that should work fine, but the above linked answer would also help. If you do want a different file for every command, then you'd probably want to implement something that triggers in the command prompt - possibly by implementing `$PROMPT_COMMAND` (`man bash` for more details) and replaces the log file for each command.

Please note that as `exec &>` captures the standard streams into a file, it basically disables and TTY applications (that draw on the screen) from running (such as `less` or `mc`). This will be true for any shell level console capture tool, unless it does a full TTY emulation (as `script` does, I believe).

Comment: Yes I want a different capture per command

Comment: Then read about `$PROMPT_COMMAND`. you'd probably want to close and reopen your `exec` every time that gets run

Comment: If I understand correctly the prompt command is executed right before the prompt is displayed so I will be able to read the last command exit code. Since the command I want to monitor is executed before the PROMPT_COMMAND when will I have a chance to redirect its output?

Comment: I think that is so, checkout the LiquidPrompt application that does something similar (capturing exit code). but I thought you already had that solved. The `PROMPT_COMMAND` allows you to set up the capture for the next command.