# How do I save the output of a script to a file?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following script:

```
LOOKUPS=/tmp/$0.LOOKUPS.$$
OK=/tmp/$0.OK.$$
KO=/tmp/$0.KO.$$
NOVENUE=/tmp/$0.NOVENUE.$$

trap "rm -f $LOOKUPS $OK $KO $NOVENUE" 0 1 2 3 4 5 13 15

tu=`$APP_SERVICE | cut -b 9-11`
date=`date +%Y%m%d`
echo "date before change: ${date}"
H=$(date +%H)
if [[ $H -ge 0 && $H -lt 9 ]]
then
        trt_date=$(date --date 'yesterday' +'%Y%m%d')
       echo "date changed: ${date}"
else
        echo "date didnt change: ${date}"
fi

grep "^$date.*lookup .. for.*" $UTP_LOG_DIR/logs.* | awk '{print $13"_"$4" "$11" "$17"="$19" "$20"="$23}' | sed 's/\[.*\]//g' | sed -e 's/string{//g' -e 's/, / /g' -e 's/=(/=/g' -e 's/)).//g' -e 's/}//g' | sort -u > $LOOKUPS

grep " OK " $LOOKUPS | awk '{print $1" "$3" "$4}' > $OK
grep " KO " $LOOKUPS | awk '{print $1" "$3" "$4}' > $KO
grep "^$date.*Can't find a venue for" $UTP_LOG_DIR/logs.* | sed 's/-$//g' | awk '{print $NF}' | sort -u > $NOVENUE

while read line
do
        if [ $(grep "$line" $OK | wc -l) -eq 0 ]
        then
                isin=$(echo $line | cut -d'_' -f1)
                feed=$(echo $line | cut -d'_' -f2,3)
                filters=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f2-)

                echo Fail lookup for $isin in feed $feed with filters: "$filters"
        fi
done < $KO

while read line
do
        if [ $(grep "$line" $OK | wc -l) -eq 0 ]
        then
                echo Cannot find venue for $line
        fi
done < $NOVENUE
```

To generate an output file, I redirect `stdout` to a file with `lookup.sh > file.txt`

But I need it to create the output file automatically.

Comment: What do you mean by automatically? Which file should it be saved to? Why can't you use redirection as you have proposed?

Comment: script will be placed in multiple hosts and one master host will order to execute the script and get the output file. I need that when generating the output file it uses a specific environment variable has its name. 

Also to avoid any problem executing the script and not output file is found.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide complete specs

Comment: @anmoreira note that all of what you describe can (and usually _should_) be handled by the process that executes the script on the different servers.

Comment: I think your problem was addressed and answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145651/using-exec-and-tee-to-redirect-logs-to-stdout-and-a-log-file-in-the-same-time)

Comment: Put updates in the question, and arrange words in to sentences (I can't workout what your are trying to say).

Comment: deeply sorry for my english!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the file, encapsulate the whole script in

```
{


} > file.txt
```

It will redirect stdout of everything within the `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always stuff into a file by e.g. `echo Something > the-file`.