# real time logging to file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, macos

I am working with a script which automatically enrolls macOS devices (installs software, sets up system preferences etc.) using Jamf.
While the script is running, I want a real-time log to appear on the desktop for the administrator to check progress etc.

Using the SE search I could only find logging to files **after** script was finished.

**Q:** how do I add real-time logging to a text-file on the desktop into my bash script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using exec and tee to redirect logs to stdout and a log file in the same time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145651/using-exec-and-tee-to-redirect-logs-to-stdout-and-a-log-file-in-the-same-time). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833676/redirect-echo-output-in-shell-script-to-logfile

Comment: `myscript | tee file.log`

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of `tee` which sends stdin to stdout and a logfile. Your command need only send to stdout which you can pipe into tee.