# Redirecting stdout and stderr from a bash script inside a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, stdout

I know that I can re-direct stdout and stderr from a script to a file such as follows, if this is executed directly on the command line :

```
sh myscript1.sh &>output.txt &
```

However if I place the above command to be executed inside another bash script in the same folder, instead of using the command line, it doesn't work.

I get the stdout and stderr on the terminal and the output.txt never gets written to. Why is this, and how do I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61931/redirect-all-subsequent-commands-stderr-using-exec

Answer (score 7):

Note that `&>` is a redirection operator that is *specific to `bash`*.  You seem to use `sh` to execute scripts from the command line (not relying on the `#!`-line in the script itself).  If you did that to a script that uses `&>`, it is definitely not guaranteed to work as `/bin/sh` may not be `bash`.

Instead, for a portable way of redirecting both standard output and standard error, use

```
./myscript.sh >output.txt 2>&1
```

Or, if you do want to use the `&>` redirection (and/or other `bash`-specific things), use `bash scriptname` to execute the `bash` script, or make sure that the script has a proper `#!`-line pointing to the `bash` executable, is executable, and then run the script as `./scriptname`.

---

In a non-`bash` shell, `utility &>file` would be the same as

```
utility & >file
```

which is the same as

```
utility &
>file
```

which would start `utility` in the background, and then create an empty file called `file` (or truncate `file` if it already existed).  There is no *error* in that command, it just doesn't do what a `bash` user might expect.

Comment: Thank you. However ./myscript.sh >output.txt 2>&1 &, this just wrote ./myscript.sh to output.txt. Strange as I have #!/bin/sh at the beginning of myscript.sh so it should have executed

Comment: @Engineer999 Huh? That makes no sense at all. Did you say that it wrote the string `./myscript.sh` into `output.txt`?  Did you put `echo` in front of that or something?